# Ensure that thrust doesnt memcpy from host to device

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have used the following method, expecting to avoid memcpy from host to device. Does thrust library ensure that there wont be a memcpy from host to device in the process?

```
void EScanThrust(float * d_in, float * d_out)
{
     thrust::device_ptr<float> dev_ptr(d_in);
     thrust::device_ptr<float> dev_out_ptr(d_out);

     thrust::exclusive_scan(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + size, dev_out_ptr);
}
```

Here `d_in` and `d_out` are prepared using `cudaMalloc` and `d_in` is filled with data using `cudaMemcpy` before calling this function

Comment: There shouldn't be any memcopying from host to device.  According to your description, there are no host pointers or data anywhere, so how would thrust copy anything from the host?  Anyway, it's trivial to verify this using a profiler such as `nvprof --print-gpu-trace ...`  A cudaMemcpy H->D will show up quite clearly in the trace if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does thrust library ensure that there wont be a memcpy from host to device in the process?

The code you've shown shouldn't involve any host->device copying.  (How could it?  There are no references anywhere to any host data in the code you have shown.)

For actual codes, it's easy enough to verify the underlying CUDA activity using a [profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#abstract), for example:

```
nvprof --print-gpu-trace ./my_exe
```

If you keep your profiled code sequences short, it's pretty easy to line up the underlying CUDA activity with the thrust code that generated that activity.  If you want to profile just a short segment of a longer sequence, then you can [turn profiling on and off](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#focusing-profiling) or else use [NVTX markers](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvtx-marker) to identify the desired range in the profiler output.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know about the `--print-gpu-trace` option